# How to submit the screencast to Facebook for permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed, posts

I want to list the user's Facebook posts (user feed). For this, we need permission, for permission we need to send the screencast of our app. Without permission, I cannot load the user feed, and so I can't screencast it. How to solve this? Where I am missing. Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: it should be possible with an app admin, right?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/app-roles

Answer (score 1):

If it is Server-to-Server App, please check this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review/resources/sample-submissions/server-to-server